# pygame: Unable to open sound as Sound object, but able to play as music?

Tags: python, pygame

The following works as expected:

```
pygame.mixer.init(frequency=22050, size=8, channels=2, buffer=2)
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('audio/beep.xm')
loop_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(loop_event)
pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1, start=00)
```

However this:

```
pygame.mixer.init(frequency=22050, size=8, channels=2, buffer=2)
pygame.init()
beep = pygame.mixer.Sound('audio/beep.xm')
beep.play()
```

Gives the following error:

```
pygame.error: Unable to open file 'audio/beep.xm'
```

I can't see any related issue to this as I am sure I am initialising pygame.mixer correctly and as it works as music it doesn't appear to be an issue with the fule itself. I have tried using the full path and variations of the path, all gave me the same error.

Comment: Can you try `'/audio/beep.xm'` or perhaps giving the full path of the file?

Comment: Should have mentioned I tried this, and got the same error

Answer (score 0):

The [Pygame Docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound)  for `pygame.mixer.Sound` state:

*The Sound can be loaded from an OGG audio file or from an uncompressed WAV*

`xm` audio files are not supported by pygame.